# One to one relationship with nullable foreign key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to create database relationship between two tables.

I have redemption codes which can be free. But one user has only one redem code.

I created two entities:

```
public class UserProfile
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    //... other fields

    public virtual RedemptionCode RedemptionCode { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class RedemptionCode
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int? UserProfileId { get; set; }
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

But when I adding a migration I have the following error:

> One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
>
> RedemptionCode_UserProfile_Source: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'RedemptionCode_UserProfile_Source' in relationship 'RedemptionCode_UserProfile'. Because the Dependent Role properties are not the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be '*'.

What do I really want? I want to store free redem codes in db and link one of them with new user in my system.

Comment: If it's *nullable*, it **cannot** be a primary key .....

Comment: @marc_s it is my misprint. I mean foreign key of course.

Comment: can you show the `User` model's code also?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the right code for the `UserProfile` class

```
public class RedemptionCode
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key,ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int? UserProfileId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserProfile")]
    public virtual UserProfile UserProfile { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

You have to move the `ForeignKey` from the property `UserProfileId` to the navigation property `UserProfile` and indicate that UserProfile is the principal in the relationship by adding the `ForeignKey` attribute to the `Id` of the `RedemptionCode` class

Comment: It look like `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]` is wrong attribute in the `RedemptionCode` table.

Comment: It is not wrong but it is not necessary as by default EntityFramework uses the Id property as a primary key and as long as it is an integer, it will be auto increment

Comment: Yes. I see this already. I will try your answer a little bit later. Thank you by the way!

Comment: You are welcome, I have already tried it and the migration was already created correctly

Comment: A migration was made but I have an exception white inserting a row in to this table: "A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column". But I dont want to reference my `redemcode` table with `profile` at once.

Comment: You are inserting a row in which table exactly?

Comment: Into the `RedemptionCode`. Like so: `context.RedemptionCodes.Add(new RedemptionCode {Code = redemcode});`